# Uniqueness of holomorphic solutions of a differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given two polynomials $p,q\in\mathbb C[z]$ consider the initial value problem
\begin{align*}
f(z)-p(z)f'(z)&=f(z^2)-q(z)f'(z^2),\qquad z\in\mathbb D,\\
f(0)&=0, \\
f'(0)&=1.
\end{align*}
Under what conditions on $p$ and $q$ are holomorphic solutions $f:\mathbb D\to\mathbb C$ unique?

Is there a methode to find any holomorphic solution of this differential equation? Can these solutions be written in terms of $p$ and $q$ only?

To be honest, I have no idea how to get started. Any ideas? All I know is that all solutions form a vector space...

Thx in advance!